# UITableView and retaining cells

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Does a `UITableView` instance send a retain message to each of its queued reusable cells?

[The point being I have a custom cell which I want to `autorelease` in a (class) method within the custom cell class.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the tableview retains the cells you return in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That's why the cell objects in the default implementation of that method are autoreleased.

Answer (score 1):

How you get the custom cell in the first place? Most likely it's retrieved via the mainBundle's loadNibNamed method which you don't have the responsibility to release it anyway.